# validation is not working in login.cs page

Tags: mysql, asp.net, entity-framework

I have created Username and password field in login page and using mysql database with entity framework in asp.net page.

Here is my asp.net code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" class="form-control" runat="server" placeholder="Username" required=""></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" class="form-control" TextMode="Password" runat="server" placeholder="Password" required=""></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnLogin" class="btn btn-primary block full-width m-b" runat="server" Text="Sign In" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

Here is my code behind:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (txtUsername.Text != null)
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Your username is correct!!!')</script>");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Please enter the Username!!!')</script>");
    }

    if (txtPassword.Text != null)
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Your password is correct!!!')</script>");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Please enter the password!!!')</script>");
    }

    contractmanagement_dbEntities dbEntities = new contractmanagement_dbEntities();
    var UserName = txtUsername.Text;
    var Password = txtPassword.Text;
    var login = from M in dbEntities.adminlogins.Where(M => M.Username == UserName && M.UserPassword == Password) select M;

    if (login.Count() > 0)
    {
        var username = txtUsername.Text;
        Session["username"] = username;
        Response.Redirect("index.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Username or password is not Valid!!!')</script>");
    }
}
```

In code behind I have set not equal to null for both username and password so how to show the error message like `Please enter the username` and `Please enter the password` if the respective username and password is empty?

Comment: You can use [RequiredFieldValidator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78xxk8k.aspx) for validation.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a hidden label for message on top of your login page and then in the code behind you can set its text to "your desired message" and make it visible like so :

```
txtLabel.Text = "Your desired message";
txtLabel.Visible = true;
```

Also, you have to move your login code to if block when both the username and password are not empty:

```
  if((txtUsername.text != null) && (txtPassword.Text != null))
{   
    contractmanagement_dbEntities dbEntities = new contractmanagement_dbEntities();
    var UserName = txtUsername.Text;
    var Password = txtPassword.Text;
    var login = from M in dbEntities.adminlogins.Where(M => M.Username == UserName && M.UserPassword == Password) select M;

    if (login.Count() > 0)
    {
        var username = txtUsername.Text;
        Session["username"] = username;
        Response.Redirect("index.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        txtLabel.Text = "Invalid Username or password";
        txtLabel.Visible = true;
    }

}
```